# Series "Bionic" is not supported by charm, supported series are: Xenial,Trusty,Yakkety

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I am trying to deploy [Openstack](https://jujucharms.com/openstack-base/) using juju and also deploy `bundle.yaml` on Ubuntu 18.04. It fails with the error

> cannot deploy bundle: series "bionic" not supported by charm, supported series are: xenial,trusty,yakkety

This is a part of the `bundle.yaml` files:

```
Machines:
  '0':
    constraints: arch=amd64 spaces=managment,^internal-mgm,^storage-cluster
    series: bionic
    tags: controller
  '1':
    constraints: arch=amd64 spaces=managment,^internal-mgm,^storage-cluster
    series: bionic
    tags: compute1
  '2':
    constraints: arch=amd64 spaces=managment,^internal-mgm,^storage-cluster
    series: bionic
    tags: compute2
  '3':
    constraints: arch=amd64 spaces=managment,^internal-mgm,^storage-cluster
    series: bionic
    tags: compute3
  '4':
    constraints: arch=amd64 spaces=managment,^internal-mgm,^storage-cluster
    series: bionic
    tags: compute4
  '5':
    constraints: arch=amd64 spaces=managment,^internal-mgm,^storage-cluster
    series: bionic
    tags: compute5
```

Comment: If you need to use then install xenial = 16.04 (supported until 2021).